# View race times in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

Is it possible to view race times in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe? I remember being able to view times in Mario Kart 64, which was great for close races because you could see when someone won by only 1/100 of a second, for example.

For [how lauded this game has been](http://www.metacritic.com/game/switch/mario-kart-8-deluxe/critic-reviews), all the 100/100 review scores and talk about how it's "perfection" or "the definitive Mario Kart", surely it must have this feature that Mario Kart 64 had 20 years ago?

Comment: Got to say, i'm missing this feature too. Was funny to see how you won by  a hair.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for does not appear in Mario Kart 8 nor Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, as the race will instantly end as soon as you finish (or as soon as all human players finish in multiplayer). Thus, it does not track the times of computer players.

Only a few Mario Karts have included this feature since MK64, because they stopped waiting for all CPUs to finish. Mario Kart Wii had this feature, but it just estimated a number for all CPUs since the race would be done when the player finished, so it wasn't actually accurate regardless.

Comment: "waiting for all CPUs to finish" is a vague excuse imo. They could simply fast simulate it as it was done in previous games, and in online mode we have to wait anyways for everybody to end the race. So, knowing how nintendo use to do the things, I would gess it's due to not hurting the sensivility of novice and bad players.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone, but I would only care about how the human players did compared to each other anyways. So it seems like this excuse about waiting could be circumvented by only tracking the human players and the CPUs that finish within the range of human players finishing. Simply don't look at CPU race time after the last place human finisher.

Comment: @spacetyper they keep the "times" in time trials in this game. I was just theorizing why it's not in the game.